# WMS configuration error reading the project file or the SLD configuration

Tags: wms, qgis-server

I downloaded the OsGeo4W-Installer and installed Apache (Windows 7). The web site localhost has an error like:

```
WMS configuration error">There was an error reading the project file or the SLD configuration.
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve this and how to connect the WMS?

The process I followed from the web site: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial#QGIS-Server-configuration

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212611/qgis-server-2-14-raises-error-reading-project-file-on-ubuntu-16-04