# QGis-Server 2.14 raises error reading project file on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, apache

I installed QGis-Server 2.14 on Ubuntu 16.04 following the instructions on [this blog](http://www.paulshapley.com/2016/07/how-to-install-qgis-server-on-ubuntu.html?showComment=1475153231712#c4163641401127840252). The `fgci` on its own is responsive and correctly replying to a GetCapabilities request like:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

However, if I point the browser to a QGis project file, like:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/project/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

The response is an error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0">
  <ServiceException code="WMS configuration error">
    There was an error reading the project file or the SLD configuration
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Using directly the command line I get a different error message:

```
$ ./qgis_mapserv.fcgi "QUERY_STRING=SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Warning 1: Unable to find driver JP2ECW to unload from GDAL_SKIP environment variable.
Content-Length: 206
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
 <ServiceException code="Service configuration error">Service unknown or unsupported</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

The Apache logs are clean. The error log is empty and the access log is reporting nothing unusual.

Are there any other logs I can look into? Any hints on what may be causing this error(s)?

**Update I**: I was able to set up logging following the suggestions by [elpaso66](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212929/21532). As he expected, QGis-Server is returning a file not found error, but the file actually exists:

```
$ tail /tmp/qgis-000.log
[8066][15:50:44] inserting pair MAP // /usr/lib/cgi-bin/project/project.qgs into the parameter map
[8066][15:50:44] MAP:/usr/lib/cgi-bin/project/project.qgs
[8066][15:50:44] REQUEST:GetCapabilities
[8066][15:50:44] SERVICE:WMS
[8066][15:50:44] VERSION:1.3.0
[8066][15:50:44] Error, configuration file '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/project/project.qgs' does not exist
[8066][15:50:44] Checking byte array is ok to set...
[8066][15:50:44] Byte array looks good, setting response...
[8066][15:50:44] Sending HTTP response
[8066][15:50:44] Request finished in 0 ms

$ ls -la /usr/lib/cgi-bin/project/project.qgs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49 Sep 29 14:41 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/project/project.qgs -> /home/desouslu/Projects/project/project.qgs

$ ls -la /home/desouslu/Projects/project/project.qgs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 desouslu desouslu 156185 Aug 16 15:40 /home/desouslu/Projects/project/project.qgs
```

**Update II**: This ended up being an issue with permissions. On Ubuntu, folders created in the home folder by default do not have execution permissions for all. A `chmod a+x` is required on the folder structure leading to the `.qgs` file, otherwise Apache fails to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with execution permissions for qgis file, additionally I had to add read permissions for all. So the file ended up having 775 permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can configure the server to automatically serve a particular project, it's normally easier to specify the project (full) path directly with the **MAP** parameter in the query string, like:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/project/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/path/to/your/project.qgs
```

To get some useful logs out of QGIS, you might want to follow the tips given in this page:
http://www.itopen.it/qgis-server-python-plugins-ubuntu-setup/lang-pref/en/

In particular see:

```
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_DEBUG 1
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE /tmp/qgis-000.log
FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 0
```

The different error messages... the first error `There was an error reading the project...` usually means that the project file was not found, the second message `Service configuration error` is caused by the way you pass the env vars, which is wrong and hence no env vars are actually passed to the script and `SERVICE` has no value inside the script:

```
/qgis_mapserv.fcgi "QUERY_STRING=SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities"
```

Should be:

```
QUERY_STRING="SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" /qgis_mapserv.fcgi
```

or with an `export ...`