# QGIS 3.4 server on Windows 10: enable logging without fcgid?

Tags: qgis, server, log

I'm running QGIS 3.4 server on Windows 10.  The docs [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/install.html#fa-http-server-configuration) say that you need to add these lines to httpd.conf to enable QGIS server logging:

```
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE /var/log/qgis/qgisserver.log
  FcgidInitialEnv QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL 0
```

(Those lines are also referenced in several other: [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/212929/19306) and [here](http://www.itopen.it/qgis-server-python-plugins-ubuntu-setup/lang-pref/en/) for example)

But those only work if mod_fcgid is installed.  Apparently you have to jump through some moving-target hoops to install mod_fcgid on Windows.

Is there a way to enable QGIS server logging without mod_fcgid?

Comment: QGIS_SERVER_LOG_FILE is deprecated and will be removed in QGIS 4. It's replaced by QGIS_SERVER_LOG_STDERR. You can have a look to https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/config.html#qgis-server-log-stderr I'm not sure how it works on windows.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know and I will use _STDERR when this is all figured out.  I was hoping you could just use SetEnv in place of FcgidInitialEnv - I tried SetEnv, and the server started but nothing appeared in the specified log file even after making sure the permissions were fully open.